# How can I upload a file in PHP large than about 2MB?

Tags: php, file-upload, large-files, ini

I am trying to allow users to upload a max of a 2GB jar file with an HTML file input and PHP.  The process works fine and it uploads the file, but only if it is small.  I have set the php.ini to this:

```
max_execution_time = 10000
max_input_time = 10000
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
```

After I did this it made all my php pages that has in it:

```
require_once("../include/config.php");
```

to load as a plain white page with NOTHING on it OR (SOMETIMES) it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare encodePassword() (previously declared in /home/duskfall/public_html/authentication/encode.php:2) in /home/duskfall/public_html/authentication/encode.php on line 80
```

On line 80 where it said it was is:

```
$coded = "";
```

Why would it do this when I only put 4 things in the php.ini. They are also the only 4 things when I created the php.ini file. It even does it when I put NOTHING in the php.ini file. Do I need to put some other things in the file?

How would I fix this problem.  Or is there a better way to do it with the php.ini and make it effect just ONE php page?

EDIT: Also I am using the host godaddy.com on a linux server if that helps at all.

Comment: that's way above goddady's limits (depends which hosting type you have)

Comment: as the error says, `$encodePassword` is being redeclared. are you sure that you're looking at the right file?

Comment: @Hamish encodePassword is a function.  That line I posted was where it said the error is in that function.  There was not a php.ini until I made it.  When I did everything stopped working.  It either gave me the error and sometimes it just loaded a blank page.  Do I need to add something more to the php.ini?

Comment: You have two functions called encode password. That's,where your error originates from

Answer (score 1):

1. Before use post_max_size you must set memory_limit.
2. post_max_size depend of memory_limit, memory_limit is must be higher than post_max_size, not equal.
3. Also post_max_size must be higher than upload_max_filesize.
   Use in php script:

   echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
   ini_set("memory_limit","30M");
   echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";

   echo ini_get("post_max_size")."\n";
   ini_set("post_max_size","20M");
   echo ini_get("post_max_size")."\n";

   echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize")."\n";
   ini_set("upload_max_filesize","19M");
   echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize")."\n";

Also:
I think you have a problem with your function encodePassword().
Try use new clear test files like:

test.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/path/to/your/phpscript" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

test.php

```
$uploaddir = '/path/to/your/dir';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Success.\n";
} else {
    echo "Error!\n";
}

echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Debug file:';
    print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: When I did that it only changed the memory_limit but the others remain the same.  I got this message:
Memory limit: 64M - NEW Memory limit: 30M - Post max: 48M - NEW Post max: 48M - Upload max: 32M - NEW Upload max: 32M